# Equivalence of two sections of some vector bundle

Tags: vector-bundles

Given a nice manifold $M$ and a vector bundle $V$ over $M$. Let $u,v$ be 2 smooth sections of $V$. We say $u$, $v$ are equivalent if there is an isomorphism $f$ of $V$, so that $u=f^*v$. Is there any mathematical theory that classifies this equivalence relation?

Comment: A priori, an isomorphism of $M$ cannot act on sections of $V$. Do you maybe mean an isomorphism of $V$?

Comment: @PanagiotisKonstantis I think you are right.  I was thinking about vector bundle of differential forms.